# Creating User Pages

Tags: mysql, url-rewriting

I have a MySQL table designated for storing usernames, passwords, etc.  In this table, one field is called "username."  I would like to create a user page for each user that gets entered into the database.  I would like the URL for any given user page to be http://foo.com/member/username.  How could I do this?

Thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 0):

Using mod_rewrite you could create a single script (foo.com/member/index.php) and re-write the url so that the server treats /member/username as /member/index.php?uid=username.

Your main script would be responsible for loading and outputting the user information.

Your rewrite would look something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([^/]+) index.php?uid=$1
```

Comment: @John: Yeah, since you'll be using .htaccess, you can use the simplified version in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... PHP and mod_rewrite

You could rewrite the url member/xyz to member.php?username=xyz and then let the php-script display some data.